# Using if & else if statements within a loop (for) for Conditional formatting

Tags: r

I have a matrix with 52 columns, 1290 rows that contains the the p values and coefficients of a loop I have successfully ran.

In this instance, I want to conditionally format one of the variable's coefficient (r) value (column 3) by appending asterisks to the end of the coefficient value, depending on the associated p value (column 19).

I have not been able to successfully append `"***"` when an exponential p value is present, I have also tried setting `options(scipen=999)` but to no avail. I have been able to isolate the 'e' present in the p value using `str_sub()` and `stri_sub()`, therefore I could use an if statement if I can get the ifs to work correctly within the loop:

```
# p<0.001 (append "***") # p<0.01 (append "**") # p<0.05 (append "*")
```

The following statement works correctly in isolation but fails when I add the below into a `for()` loop:

```
# Working asterisk append to coefficient value 
if(as.numeric(cell_id_input) < 0.05) {
cell_id_out <- paste0(cell_id_out,"*", sep="")     
}
```

Loop over each row in matrix 'dta' using columns specified (3 and 19 only) and append asterisk if meets following criteria:

```
for (j in 1:nrow(dta)){
  cell_id_input <- dta[j,19] # Column that contains associated (p) values for 'cell_id_out'
  cell_id_out <- dta[j,3] { # Column that contains the coefficient (r) value associated with 'cell_id_input' 
  if(as.numeric(cell_id_input) < 0.001) { 
    cell_id_out <- paste0(cell_id_out,"***", sep="") 
} else if (as.numeric(cell_id_input) < 0.01) {
    cell_id_out <- paste0(cell_id_out,"**", sep="") 
} else if(as.numeric(cell_id_input) < 0.05) {
    cell_id_out <- paste0(cell_id_out,"*", sep="") 
} else {
    cell_id_out <- paste(cell_id_out)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df=data.frame("a"=c(0.1,0.6,0.00000000001,0.000000002),
           "b"=c(1,4,3,5),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$a = as.character(df$a)
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (as.numeric(df$a[i])<0.05){
    df$a[i]=paste0(df$a[i],"*")
  }
}
       a b
1    0.1 1
2    0.6 4
3 1e-11* 3
4 2e-09* 5
```

This works for me. You can adapt it to your case. Your problem is that you are assigning the result to `cell_id_out` variable, not to the `dta` dataframe.